# How to parse this specific Data in Jsoup

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

im not sure how to parse the "bundesweit" and the date string in jsoup, since its both the same class name (col2)

```
<strong><a href="/stellenangebote/109499-python-entwickler-gui-testing?page=1&amp;query%5Bcity%5D=&amp;query%5Bradius%5D=100&amp;query%5Btext%5D=Python" title="Python-Entwickler (m/w) GUI Testing">Python-Entwickler (m/w) GUI Testing</a></strong>
<br>
<a class="job-offer-teaser-company" href="/unternehmen/ruecker-gmbh" title="Rücker">Rücker</a>
</div>
<div class='col2'>
bundesweit
</div>
<div class='col2'>
08.12.2013
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
Elements jobTitleElement = element.select("a");
                        Elements companyNameElement = element.select(".job-offer-teaser-company");
                        Elements locationElement = element.select(".cal2");
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the HTML follows the same structure, just select them both and then split them up using indexing.

```
//Get the HTML
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html); 
//or
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

//Select the elements
Elements col2Elements = doc.select("div.col2"); //This will return a collection of Element objects
String firstElement = col2Elements.get(0).text(); //Get the first
String secondElement = col2Elements.get(1).text(); //Get the second
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following codes:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements elements = doc.getElementsByClass("col2");
String bundesweitContent = elements.get(0).text();
System.out.println(bundesweitContent); // You get "bundesweit"
```

reference:

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document

http://jsoup.org/apidocs/